# ThreadPool QueueUserWorkItem error on target with HttpContext

Tags: c#, .net, threadpool

I have this class which fires a method and forget it..  the only problem is, if the method  am calling has an `HttpContext` it throws `NullReferenceException`.

My gues is that I can't use `Httpcontext` inside the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(dynamicInvokeShim, new TargetInfo(d, args));` because I am getting `NullReferenceException`  is there a work around for it?

Method with `Httpcontext`:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(string name)
{
    return (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Cache[name];
}
```

method that fires and forget a method:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace XGen.Kuapo.BLL
{
  public class AsyncHelper
  {
      class TargetInfo
      {
          internal TargetInfo(Delegate d, object[] args)
          {
              Target = d;
              Args = args;
          }

          internal readonly Delegate Target;
          internal readonly object[] Args;
      }

      private static WaitCallback dynamicInvokeShim = new WaitCallback(DynamicInvokeShim);

      public static void FireAndForget(Delegate d, params object[] args)
      {
          ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(dynamicInvokeShim, new TargetInfo(d, args));
      }

      static void DynamicInvokeShim(object o)
      {
          try
          {
              TargetInfo ti = (TargetInfo)o;
              ti.Target.DynamicInvoke(ti.Args);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              // Only use Trace as is Thread safe
              System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: "It throws an error" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to translate the erro to english, beacause its not my default language

Comment: the error is: `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like usr said: `HttpContext.Current` is only available on the thread executing a request, and a thread pool thread you started is not that same thread.

However, if you want to access the ASP.NET cache, you can also use `HttpRuntime.Cache`, which is a static property which is available from each thread. (`HttpContext.Current.Cache` simply returns `HttpRuntime.Cache` so you don't need to worry about any difference.)

Note that it is ill advised to pass the HttpContext instance received from `HttpContext.Current` to another thread: by the time the other thread runs, the request corresponding with the captured HttpContext could already have ended, so you could end up with an HttpContext instance that is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `HttpContext.Current` is available only on the thread executing your HTTP request. A simple fix is to pass the result of the expression `(DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Cache[name]` to the thread so the thread itself does not need to access the `HttpContext`. Alternatively, pass the `HttpContext.Current` object to the thread.

How to pass data to a thread or task is out of scope for this question but you'll find a lot of info about it on the web.